# Implications of using NetHttpTransport() over GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()

Tags: java, security, google-api, google-workspace

I'm using `google-api-services-admin-directory` in a project, and the docs recommend using `GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()` as the HTTP transport, but I kept getting certificate errors that I think were cause by my proxy. I switched over to `new NetHttpTransport()` instead, and everything now works fine, but I just want to make sure I'm not compromising on security by doing so.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Rhys

Answer (score 1):

Hope you don't mind the late reply. I was having the same issue and did some research.

According to the [Java Docs of Google API](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/javanet/GoogleNetHttpTransport.html) the `GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport()` takes into account website certificates to use for Google APIs. However:

> This helper method doesn't provide for customization of the NetHttpTransport, such as the ability to specify a proxy.

This confirms what you were saying about the certificates errors you are getting being caused by your proxy.

It is recommended, security wise, that instead of `new NetHttpTransport()` to use the  `NetHttpTransport.Builder` in order to get a Trusted Transport for a specified proxy, as show on the link's example:

```
 static HttpTransport newProxyTransport() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
   NetHttpTransport.Builder builder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
   builder.trustCertificates(GoogleUtils.getCertificateTrustStore());
   builder.setProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 3128)));
   return builder.build();
 }
```